# How do I capture square brackets in regular expressions

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a series of text elements that contains brackets:

```
[PropertyID]
,[ParcelID]
,[Score]
,[Score1]
```

How do I capture the elements WITH the brackets?
I tried this and it didn't work: `([\\[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\]])`
also `(\\[[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\])`

I'm trying to perform some text replacement in notepad++ and It says It can't find it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
\[[^][]*]
```

The  `\[` matches a `[`, then `[^][]*` matches zero or more characters other than `[` and `]` (since it is a negated character class with a `*` quantifier applied to it) and `]` matches a literal `]`.

This will match `[...]` substrings with no `]` and `[` inside them.

The first `[` must be escaped to match a *literal `[` symbol*. When you use `[\\[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\]]`, the first `[` starts a character class that matches 1 symbol, either `\`, or `[`, `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, one or more times (`+`), and then a literal `\]]` sequence (see [what your regex actually matches](https://regex101.com/r/xG1jA6/1)).

[image]

Comment: That did it.  I'll accept when the timer allows.  Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. I added a demo to what one of your regex really matches and you will get the point. Note that `]` do not have to be escaped outside a character class to denote literal `]` symbols.

Comment: This helps so much.  Thanks.  Regular Expressions are always underestimated.  When coupled with Notepad++, it's a great tool.